# Артефакт. Как с ним работать? Как его правильно читать и делать выводы?

Tags: binary, артефакты

Это отчёт по результатам сканирования binary check одного из бинарных файлов. Необходимо изучить отчёт и предложить рекомендации по устранению уязвимостей и рассказать кратко что это такое и зачем нужно.

```
+ASLR +STACK-PROT +READ-ONLY-RELOC +IMMEDIATE-BIND ~FORTIFY-SOURCE(+memcpy,+printf,+longjmp,+snprintf,+fprintf,+sprintf,
+poll,+vfprintf,+fdelt,+memset,+vsnprintf,+strcat,!strncpy,!vfprintf,!ppoll,
!memcpy,!syslog,!asprintf,!fgets,!fread,!stpcpy,!ttyname_r,!memset,!fprintf,
!explicit_bzero,!strncat,!realpath,!vasprintf,!pread,!vsnprintf,!pread64,
!printf,!recvfrom,!poll,!read,!sprintf,!memmove,!gethostname,!getgroups,
!recv,!strcpy,!snprintf,!getcwd,!readlink,!strcat)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу понять как с этим работать, может кто может приложить качественную литерату по данному вопросу, буду блпгодарен.

Comment: Кратко -- это какая-то серверная программа, работающая с сокетами, скорее всего написанная в linux. Что именно вам предложено устранять, не слишком понятно (могу предположить, что различные уязвимости), лучше явно пропишите в тексте вопроса

Comment: Это всё что дано, больше нет не чего конкретного

Comment: Ну, значит остальное было сказано на лекциях или практических занятиях или написано в рекомендованной по этому предмету (кстати, как он у вас называется?) литературе. Вспоминайте и формулируйте вопросы так, чтобы они были понятны не только тем, кто учится с вами вместе.

Comment: Это задание к техническому собеседованию, до этого с подобным я не сталкивался и не чего подобного не изучал, формулировка дана как в задании, я даже не знаю что тут можно добавить

Comment: Если в этой фирме так формулируют свои ТЗ, то трижды подумайте -- нужна ли она вам

Comment: А вообще, чего вас понесло в InfoSec?

Comment: Учусь на специалиста по информационной безопасности, но с такими задачками мы даже близко на учёбе не сталкивались

Comment: Ну, да. Тема очень широкая, от простейших рекомендаций, типа *"мойте руки перед едой"*, до meltdown-spectre (или что там нового появилось?). Наверное настоящих спецов, которые видят тему в полном объеме почти нет. Насколько понимаю, то о чем вас спрашивают относится к fork-exec в nix*-ах. Т.е. по идее надо бы посмотреть код ядра (разных версий) и попробовать сломать (например, запустив что-то свое став рутом), а потом понять, что надо изменить в ОС, чтобы этого не происходило. Возни (на мой взгляд) тут будет много, но спецом в куче очень узких областей стать можно

Comment: Я вообще начал резко теряться в этом всём сейчас, я обычно как то больше увлекался безопасностью вычислительных сетей, уже даже интересные идеи на диплом начали появляться, а тут предложили попробовать что-то новое с неплохим окладом, и накидали потренироваться всякого разного (C/C++ и Go для анализа кода, поиска уяз, исправления ошибок, вот этот астифакт, и парочку заданий для работы с docker`ом по типу как проникнуть на host систему или проанализировать конфигурацию и придумать как можно проэксплуатировать обнаруженные уязвимости)

Comment: Хоть в чем-то конкретно по вопросу я вряд ли смогу помочь (InfoSec я не занимаюсь, т.е. у меня только какое-то общее представление о ней)